# Is there a way to shift multiple rows from pandas dataframes with different lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the image attached
[image: Dataframe I am working with]
Each column with name Wells 1,2,..,n have different beginnings of production. Some of them at month 5 or month 9, some after 24 months.
I want to normalize the start date for all of them. That is, shifting all non-zero values up. 
I know that this sample code works well only for Well 7 but I want to optimize it and do all of them at once.

```
df['Well 7'] = df['Well 7'].shift(-1)
```

I am new to pandas, i tried in a loop but the dataframe name does not work in a loop.

```
  df['Well {0}'].format(well)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Time will continue starting at 1?

Comment: Yes, time will continue to start at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to detect Well columns ,**cols_Well** in example (this step could be omitted and select columns yourself).

Then we can calculate the number of 0 initials with [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), **shift_cols_Well** in example.
Therefore this series tells us the parameter to pass to [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
cols_Well = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Well')]
shift_cols_Well = df[cols_Well].ne(0).cumsum().eq(0).sum()
#shift_cols_Well = df[cols_Well].eq(0).cumprod().sum()
for col in cols_Well:
    df[col] = df[col].shift(-shift_cols_Well.loc[col])
```

---

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':range(1,10),
                   'Well 1':[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'Well 2':[0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

   Time  Well 1  Well 2
0     1       0       0
1     2       2       0
2     3       3       3
3     4       4       4
4     5       5       5
5     6       6       6
6     7       7       7
7     8       8       8
8     9       9       9
```

---

**Solution Example**

```
cols_Well = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Well')]
shift_cols_Well = df[cols_Well].ne(0).cumsum().eq(0).sum()
#shift_cols_Well = df[cols_Well].eq(0).cumprod().sum()
for col in cols_Well:
    df[col] = df[col].shift(-shift_cols_Well.loc[col])
print(df)

   Time  Well 1  Well 2
0     1     2.0     3.0
1     2     3.0     4.0
2     3     4.0     5.0
3     4     5.0     6.0
4     5     6.0     7.0
5     6     7.0     8.0
6     7     8.0     9.0
7     8     9.0     NaN
8     9     NaN     NaN
```

---

**Detail**

```
print(shift_cols_Well)
Well 1    1
Well 2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can also get the shifts with `.eq(0).cumprod().sum()`.

Comment: right, good suggestion:), I don't know how fast `cumprod` is with respect to `cumsum + eq` @ALollz

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df.columns:
    while df[col].iloc[0]==0:
        df[col]= df[col].shift(-1)
```

Comment: this is very inefficient, imagine that you have to apply shift to the same column 100 times instead of once